# On fraction of products

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fractions, periodic-functions, fractional-part

Consider $\frac1{101}=0.00990099\dots$ and $\frac1{143}=0.00699300699300\dots$ and $\frac1{101\times 143}=0.0000692376930000692376930000\dots$.

Now $990\times69930=69230700$ which is almost $69237693$.

Is it possible to get exact equality? If so when should I truncate the fractions before multiplying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You ask whether it is possible to have
$$\frac a{10^n-1}\cdot\frac b{10^m-1}=\frac{ab}{10^k-1}. $$
Except for the trivial cases $a=0$ or $b=0$, this would require
$$ 10^k-1=(10^n-1)(10^m-1)=10^{n+m}-10^n-10^m+1.$$
As the left is $\equiv-1\pmod {10}$ and the right $\equiv +1\pmod{10}$, this cannot happen.

Comment: why $a/(10^n-1)$? I think I am looking at $round(a/(10^n-1))$.